# Conditional definition (/;)

Tags: function-construction, functional-style, conditional

I defined the following functions

```
CreatorQ[_] := False;
AnnihilatorQ[_] := False;

CreatorQ[q] := True;
AnnihilatorQ[p] := True;
CreatorQ[J[n_]] /; n < 0 := True;
AnnihilatorQ[J[n_]] /; n > 0 := True;
```

and when I ask for

```
Assuming[r < 0, CreatorQ[J[r]]]
```

I get `False` instead of `True`. I know that probabilly it's because Matehamtica doesn't evaluate the r, but I have no idea how to change the code in order to get the correct answer.
Thanks

Comment: I don't thing the problem is with evaluating the `r` symbol or with the downvalues of the function `CreatorQ`. I think `Assuming` isn't doing what you think it should. It simply adds the assumption into $Assumptions, which some functions like `Simplify` use. This _I think_ does not have any effect on user defined functions, unless they use `Refine`, `Simplify`, `FullSimplify` or `FunctionExpand`

Comment: I think the "problem" is the `/;` because if I define `CreatorQ[J[n_]]:= n<0` it works!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the pattern-matching in `CreatorQ` doesn't have any sort of knowledge of the assumption you're making about `r`, so the `Condition` won't fire. You can, as you commented, get around this by just redefining `CreatorQ` to return the inequality, which will remain unevaluated if `n` doesn't have a value that can be compared to 0:

```
ClearAll[CreatorQ];
CreatorQ[_] = False;
CreatorQ[q] := True;
CreatorQ[J[n_]] := n < 0;
```

Now, as in Vaghan Tumanyan's comment, you need to use a function that will make use of the assumptions introduced by `Assuming`. In this case, `Simplify` is completely adequate:

```
Assuming[r < 0, Simplify@CreatorQ[J[r]]]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need:

```
CreatorQ[_] := False;
AnnihilatorQ[_] := False;

CreatorQ[q] := True;
AnnihilatorQ[p] := True;
CreatorQ[J[n_]] /; Simplify[n < 0] := True;
AnnihilatorQ[J[n_]] /; Simplify[n > 0] := True;

Assuming[r < 0, CreatorQ[J[r]]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```